# How to replicate the functionality of delivered "File Engagement" lwc card?

Tags: soql, lightning-web-components, contentversion, contentdocument

In our org we have a need to programmatically replicate the functionality of delivered  “File Engagement” component/card.

Here is a snapshot from our live org, on a ContentDocument view page: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu8l1.png]

Since this is from the live org, we assume that this component is using a delivered object, and counts the Views and Downloads.

We figured that [ContentVersionHistory object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversionhistory.htm) actually holds the download details, and we can replicate the 'Downloads' number by counting the related rows with `field = 'contentVersionDownloaded'`. However, when we run the same SOQL query with only changing `field = 'contentVersionViewed'`, we get 0 results. Not only for this specific contentVersionId, but any other contentVersionIds.

My question is, somehow, am I missing something in ContentVersionHistory, or is this information actually stored in a different object? Maybe in an aggregated form as view stat/count?

Comment: I ran the following in the dev console `SELECT Id, ContentVersionId, ContentVersion.ContentDocumentId, CreatedDate,Field FROM ContentVersionHistory WHERE Field='contentVersionViewed'` and got 8 results back. Now here is the odd bit... They are all from 2013-07. There isn't anything since then. I'm wondering if Salesforce changed the way they track views on  Files.

Comment: Even though I am a System Administrator in our org, and have the special permission named "Query All Files", until I manually shared the specific file with my user, I was not able to query ContentVersionHistory. Nothing, not even the `field = 'contentVersionDownloaded'`. Only after I shared the file(s) manually, then I was able to query them off of ContentVersionHistory. Just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ContentVersionHistory isn't working I have an uneasy feeling that the way to get the information is from the EventLogFile for [Content Transfer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_contenttransfer.htm). This would likely be a paid feature to access that data.

The docs do indicate that the `VersionRenditionDownload` Transaction_Type would track the file previews, which agrees with the Spring '19 release notes on what counts as a view under the "File Engagement" control.

> NOTE Only file types that display a preview are counted. Views and downloads through public links or content deliveries aren’t counted in the file engagement stats for files in the org. [Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_file_detail_stats.htm&type=5&release=218)

Comment: I have actually recently paid for the service to get the full EventLogFile. `VersionRenditionDownload` is there, yes, but it only displays a file was viewed. Not necessarily which file. I have confirmed with Salesforce support that it is the expected behavior.

Comment: It is really interesting that somehow "File Engagement" card is displaying the actual Views count by pulling from the live org, not from EventLogFile. I am thinking there must be a way... maybe SOQL level additional security or something (a total speculation on my part).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

Component:

```
    <aura:component description="test" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="statItems" access="global" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.statItems}" var="item">
        {!item.count}
        {!item.label}
    </aura:iteration>

    {!v.body}

</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
    ({
    doInit : function (cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.doInitHelper(cmp, event, helper);
    }
});
```

Helper

```
({
    doInitHelper : function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var currentStatItems = cmp.getReference("v.statItems");

        $A.createComponent(
            "forceContent:statsPanel",
            {recordId: '0697A000001IFebQAG',
                statItems: currentStatItems},
            function(newButton, status, errorMessage){
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    console.log('SUCCESS')
                } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                } else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Your contribution is welcome. But usually "code dump" answers are frowned upon on SFSE. I understand the original question was "How to replicate functionality?" and I assume that your code does that. But if there is any *why* it works helpful explanation you can add - however brief - to the *how* of your code, please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/384760/edit) your answer to add it.